# Division of two upper incomplete gamma function

Tags: gamma-function, gamma-distribution

Is there a simpler expression for $\frac{\gamma(aN,\ abN)}{\gamma(N,\ bN)}$ where $\gamma$ is lower incomplete gaamma function, a>1 and b > 0. Both N and a are integers.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I found the answer in the title.

Comment: There is a recurrence relation on the integer exponent, but in your case, $N$ and $aN$ are far apart. And I doubt that there is any relation on the second argument. So I strongly lean towards a no.